# "One-way" en-/decryption

Tags: javascript, cryptography, webcrypto-api, webcrypto

Say I have a device that produces sensitive data and sends it off to a server for storage.

The device itself should not be able to decrypt the data (protecting against an attack of the device), but a user should be able to log in to the server and view the decrypted data, however, the decrypted data should never exist anywhere but in the users browser (don't care about caching issues etc.).

Since I don't want to store any decryption keys, it must be a passphrase provided by the user to the browser.

What would be the least bad way to achieve this, preferrably using the WebCrypto API?

Comment: I dont understand the question. You send a encrypted file to a client from your server and then decrypt it before showing it to them on the page. That's all possible and isn't "bad". Check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/decrypt

Comment: Sorry if being unclear, it's the other way around: the "device" sends encrypted data to the server. The user then logs in to the server and decrypts the data using a passphrase in the web browser. Hence, a public/private key pair needs to be deterministically generated from a passphrase. I guess PBKDF2 could be used to provide entropy from the passphrase but how do I then generate a public/private key pair going from that? The device should only store the key used for encryption such that even if that device gets compromised the attacker can't decrypt the data on the server.

Comment: 1. create an ECDH key pair in the browser based on the password, 2. send the public key to the device, 3. encrypt using ECIES, lookup IES on Wikipedia, 4. store on server, 5. when required, let user enter password to recreate the key pair and thus the private decryption key. This is not a programming question however, you should take a look at [security.se].